# Insertar datos a tablas relacionadas C#

Tags: c#, sql

quiero almacenar en una tabla llamada películas, donde tiene una clave foránea id_genero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla generos la tengo poblada con 4 generos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en C# Tengo paso por string el comando SQL pero me dice que hay un error en la clave foranea id_genero.

```
 public void Registrar()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=EMILIANO-PC ; database=VideoClub ; integrated security = true");
                conexion.Open();
                string cadena = "insert into pelicula(nombre_pelicula,web_pelicula,descripcion,anio,idgenero) values ('" + txtnombre.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtweb.Text.Trim() + "' , '" + txtdescripcion.Text.Trim() + "', '" + txtanio.Text + " ', '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + " ')";
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");

                conexion.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());

            }
        }
```

ahora el error que me sale es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le agregue .ToString al SelectValue

Comment: que dato viene en selectedvalue?

Comment: @gbianchi vienen los id que puse en la tabla géneros, estos son: 3,4,5,6

Comment: y en la tabla estan como string o numericos?

Comment: @gbianchi numericos, podes chequearlo arriba en las dos capturas que publique

Comment: @gbianchi Ahi edite la duda

Comment: Dos cosas.. si es numerico no deberia ir entre comillas simples.. y ese error ya tiene una respuesta en el sitio y no tiene nada que ver con lo que estas planteando...

Comment: Cuál es la línea 78 en tu código? Si es la que comienza con "string cadena" pon un punto de interrupción ahí y revisa cada variable de esa línea, alguna debe ser null y sea el origen del problema

Answer (score 2):

La manera en que estas realizando la consulta es susceptible a una `inyección SQL` por seguridad debes trabajar con consultas preparadas.

El error que te esta generando probablemente tiene que ver con el `SelectedValue`. Debes colocar un `breakpoint` al inicio del método e ir paso a paso revisando las propiedades de los objetos y los controles procurando que ninguno este llegando `null`.

```
using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("server=EMILIANO-PC; database=VideoClub; integrated security=true"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO pelicula(nombre_pelicula,web_pelicula,descripcion,anio,idgenero) VALUES (@nombre,@web,@descripcion,@anio,@valorSelect)", cnx))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtnombre.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@web", txtweb.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", txtdescripcion.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anio", txtanio.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valorSelect", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola mi recomendación es que utilices `SqlCommand.Parameters, por que utilizar esta propiedad: Por lo general las variables que insertamos en la base de datos provienen de una caja de texto, lo que significa que en tu caso esta expuesto a ataques malintencionados por lado del usuario.

Este es un ejemplo de como lo puede implementar ya que seria mucho mas fácil de leer el código espero esto te ayude.

```
public void Registrar()
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=EMILIANO-PC ; database=VideoClub ; integrated security = true"));
        {
            conexion.Open();
            string cadena = @"insert into pelicula(nombre_pelicula,web_pelicula,descripcion,anio,idgenero) 
                            values(@nombre,@web,@descripcion,@anio,@valorSelect)";                   
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtnombre.Text.Trim());
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@web", txtweb.Text.Trim());
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", txtdescripcion.Text.Trim());
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anio", txtanio.Text);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valorSelect", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");

            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

también acuérdate de verificar las variables con pruebas unitarias, para garantizar que el valor es el que necesitas.